# Use System.load on Android?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load a library in Android from its internal storage (I'm having the user download it externally, so as to reduce the apk size)

But whenever I execute System.load() in the activity, I get these errors:

```
Localized Message: dlopen failed: couldn't map "/storage/emulated/0/libtest.so" segment 2: Permission denied
Message: dlopen failed: couldn't map "/storage/emulated/0/libtest.so" segment 2: Permission denied
```

I also tried copying the .so file to /data/local/tmp and loading it from there, but was presented with the same error.

Is there any workaround around this?

Comment: Can you open the file for read from the same location? While permission to access "/storage/emulated/0" is quite reasonable, same error for "/data/local/tmp" looks strange. At any rate, I strongly recommend to download "libtest.so" to app private storage (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) that does not require extra permissions and is protected from other apps.

Comment: That just gives me file not found error. Though I explicitly verify that it is there.

dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.packagename/files/libtest.so" not found

Comment: "I explicitly verify that it is there" - how?

Comment: It's a rooted phone, so simply doing an 'ls' in the adb shell in that dir.

Comment: Path `/data/user/0/com.packagename/files/` is not  *real* path; it may be available from shell, but not from the app. You probably need `/data/data/com.packagename/files`. This still does not explain the behavior for `/data/local/tmp`.

Comment: Yeah. That folder is what is returned as the internal storage in android. It s a symlink  to the /data/data/package folder. I'm stumped by the behaviour too.

Comment: So, is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Which API level are you targeting?, For API level>=23 you need to provide dynamic run time permissions.

Comment: It's 23, but I am granting it the storage permissions.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Try this: 
1) Copy the Shared Object in local application directory using "getAppContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir".
2) Load the Shared objects from this location.
3) Keep your TargetAPILevel as 22 instead of 23.

Answer (score -2):

I see the Permission denied,you can try to set the file permission to 777

Comment: Did you test it?